# Streamplot and animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is :

```
    myimages=[]
    xvalues, yvalues =np.meshgrid(arange(-8, 8, 1), arange(-8, 8, 1))
    xdot=yvalues
    fig1=plt.figure()
    for i in range(np.size(t,0)):
        ydot=-alpha*yvalues-np.sin(xvalues)+I*sin(2*t[i])
        imgplot=plt.streamplot(xvalues, yvalues, xdot, ydot)
        myimages.append(imgplot)
    my_anim = ArtistAnimation(fig1, myimages, interval=100, blit=False, 
    repeat_delay=100)
    plt.show()
```

What I want to do here is to animate the phase potrait. But everytime "TypeError: 'StreamplotSet' object is not iterable" is the error message that crops out. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer, https://genkuroki.github.io/documents/Jupyter/20170624%20Examples%20of%20animations%20in%20Julia%20by%20PyPlot%20and%20matplotlib.animation.html. Insert `plot()`.

Comment: ArtistAnimation would require a list of lists of artists, `myimages.append([imgplot])`.